# Avoid unchecked assignment in a map with multiple value types?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I'm having trouble with a warning in Java 7:

```
Unchecked assignment: 'java.lang.Class' to 'java.lang.Class<T>'
```

I'm getting it on the line `Class<T> type = typeMap.get(key);` in the get function below.

Basically what I'm trying to do here is I want to store a bunch of key/value pairs of unknown types (but all are descendants of Object with the exception of null), but not lose the type. So I created a class with the following content using generics. It has two maps (one to store the data and one to store the class type:

```
    private Map<String, Object>  dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Class> typeMap = new HashMap<>();

    public  <T> void put(String key, T instance){
        dataMap.put(key, instance);
        if (instance == null){
            typeMap.put(key,null);
        }
        else {
            typeMap.put(key, instance.getClass());
        }
    }

    public <T> T get(String key){
        Class<T> type = typeMap.get(key);
        if (type == null){
            return null;
        }
        return type.cast(dataMap.get(key));
    }
```

It runs just fine, but the warning is annoying me.  Is there any way to get Java to do this cast without complaining (other than suppressing it)? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  How about in Java 8 as I haven't really had a chance to dive into it yet?

Thanks!

Comment: The cast _will_ be unsafe.  Suppressing the warning might make you feel better, but your code isn't actually safe.

Comment: Have you tried private Map<String, Class<T>> typeMap = new HashMap<>()?

Comment: Do you know the types that will be used within the map? or do you wish it to hold ANY types?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The reason what you've shown is unsafe is that with this assignment:

```
Class<T> type = typeMap.get(key);
```

`T` does not need to have anything to do with the `Class` retrieved from the map. `T` is always inferred from the surrounding context of the call to `get`. For example I can do this sequence of calls:

```
// T is inferred from the arguments as String (which is fine)
example.put("k", "v");
// T is inferred from the return value target type as Integer
Integer i = example.get("k");
```

Inside the `get` method, `String.class` is correctly retrieved from the type map, but an unchecked conversion is made to `Class<Integer>`. The call to `type.cast(...)` doesn't throw, because the value retrieved from the data map is a `String`. An implicit checked cast then *actually* happens to the *return value*, casting it to `Integer` and a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

This strange interaction is due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

---

So, when we are storing multiple types in a single data structure, there are a number of ways to approach it, depending on what our needs are.

#### 1. We can forego compilation checks if there is no way to perform them.

Storing the `Class` is pointless for the most part here because, as I showed above, it doesn't perform a useful validation. So we could redesign the map along the following lines:

```
class Example {
    private final Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();

    void put(String k, Object v) {
        m.put(k, v);
    }

    Object getExplicit(String k) {
        return m.get(k);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    <T> T getImplicit(String k) {
        return (T) m.get(k);
    }
}
```

`getExplicit` and `getImplicit` do a similar thing but:

```
String a = (String) example.getExplicit("k");
// the generic version allows an implicit cast to be made
// (this is essentially what you're already doing)
String b = example.getImplicit("k");
```

In both cases we're just relying on our own awareness as a programmer to not make mistakes.

Suppressing warnings isn't necessarily bad, it's just important to understand what they actually mean and what the implications are.

#### 2. Pass a `Class` to `get` so the return value must be valid.

This is the way I've seen it done typically.

```
class Example {
    private final Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();

    void put(String k, Object v) {
        m.put(k, v);
    }

    <T> T get(String k, Class<T> c) {
        Object v = m.get(k);
        return c.isInstance(v) ? c.cast(v) : null;
    }
}

example.put("k", "v");
// returns "v"
String s = example.get("k", String.class);
// returns null
Double d = example.get("k", Double.class);
```

But, of course, it means we need to pass two parameters to `get`.

#### 3. Parameterize the keys.

This is a novel but more advanced and it may or may not be more convenient.

```
class Example {
    private final Map<Key<?>, Object> m = new HashMap<>();

    <V> Key<V> put(String s, V v) {
        Key<V> k = new Key<>(s, v);
        put(k, v);
        return k;
    }

    <V> void put(Key<V> k, V v) {
        m.put(k, v);
    }

    <V> V get(Key<V> k) {
        Object v = m.get(k);
        return k.c.isInstance(v) ? k.c.cast(v) : null;
    }

    static final class Key<V> {
        private final String k;
        private final Class<? extends V> c;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Key(String k, V v) {
            // this cast will always be safe unless
            // the outside world is doing something fishy
            // like using raw types
            this(k, (Class<? extends V>) v.getClass());
        }

        Key(String k, Class<? extends V> c) {
            this.k = k;
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return k.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return (o instanceof Key<?>) && ((Key<?>) o).k.equals(k);
        }
    }
}
```

So e.g.:

```
Key<Float> k = example.put("k", 1.0f);
// returns 1.0f
Float f = example.get(k);
// returns null
Double d = example.get(new Key<>("k", Double.class));
```

This might make sense if the entries are known or predictable so we can have something like:

```
final class Keys {
    private Keys() {}
    static final Key<Foo> FOO = new Key<>("foo", Foo.class);
    static final Key<Bar> BAR = new Key<>("bar", Bar.class);
}
```

Then we don't have to construct a key object any time a retrieval is done. This works very well especially for adding some strong typing to stringly-typed scenarios.

```
Foo foo = example.get(Keys.FOO);
```

#### 4. Don't have a map any kind of object can be put in, use polymorphism of some kind.

When possible and not too cumbersome, it's a good option. If there is a common behavior that the different types are used for, make it an interface or superclass so we don't have to use casting.

A simple example might be like this:

```
// bunch of stuff
Map<String, Object> map = ...;

// store some data
map.put("abc", 123L);
map.put("def", 456D);

// wait awhile
awhile();

// some time later, consume the data
// being particular about types
consumeLong((Long) map.remove("abc"));
consumeDouble((Double) map.remove("def"));
```

And we could instead substitute something like this:

```
Map<String, Runnable> map = ...;

// store operations as well as data
// while we know what the types are
map.put("abc", () -> consumeLong(123L));
map.put("def", () -> consumeDouble(456D));

awhile();

// consume, but no longer particular about types
map.remove("abc").run();
map.remove("def").run();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to assign an element of type `Class` to a variable of type `Class<T>`.  Of course that's an unchecked assignment.  You seem to be implementing a heterogeneous map.  Java (and any other strongly-typed language) has no way to express the value type of your map in a statically-type-safe way.

That is because the element types are only known at runtime.  Expecting the compiler to statically type-check things that are not yet known is asking too much of it.  The compiler can't even do reasonable static type inference, so expecting it to predict the future for dynamic type inference is really a stretch.