# What should be the return type of generic type implementation in java

Tags: java, generics, return-type

Refering to the following code snippet, I have a interface `Splitter` which takes generic type parameters `T` and `V`. There is one implementation which is `CompanySplitterImpl`. There could be many such implementations.

```
public interface Splitter<T, V> {
    V[] split(T arg);
}

public class CompanySplitterImpl
implements Splitter<Company, Department> {

    @Override
    public Department[] split(Company comp) {

        return comp.getDepartment();
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a factory method which returns different implementation based on a key parameter value passed in to the factory method.

```
// Factory method to return different Implementation of Splitter
// (Is Splitter return type correct?)
public static Splitter getSplitter(String key) {

    return new CompanySplitterImpl(); // Is this correct?
}
```

My question is what is the correct manner of returning instance of different implementation of `Splitter<K, V>`?

```
// Client to call factory method...
// Not sure what will be type argument for Splitter type
Splitter<?> split = getSplitter("dummyKey");
```

At the client side, What will be the type argument for Splitter type?

Comment: Are you attached to the idea of using `String` as a key? Note that `Splitter` is a [raw type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664) and probably not a good idea. You're losing type safety. Related: [*"Avoid unchecked assignment in a map with multiple value types?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22468599/2891664)

Comment: also, you should try to avoid arrays with generic types -- use `List<V>` instead. The reasons are a tad complicated, but basically generics can make it very easy to avoid the type safety benefits of generics.

Comment: `CompanySplitterImpl` is a `Splitter<Company, Department>`, just as you defined it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Splitter` is a raw type. You should not use raw types. Since the key (a `String`) carries no type information, it is not possible to infer the type parameters from the argument passed to `getSplitter`. Therefore, the only way to avoid raw types is to make the return type `Splitter<?, ?>`.

This is ugly and forces the caller of the method to cast:

```
Splitter<Company, Department> split = (Splitter<Company, Department>) getSplitter("dummyKey");
```

A better way of doing this is to use a key that carries type information, and the usual way to do this is to use `Class<T>` objects.

```
public static <T, V> Splitter<T, V> getSplitter(Class<T> key1, Class<V> key2) {

    if (key1 == Company.class && key2 == Department.class)
        return (Splitter<T, V>) new CompanySplitterImpl();

    // more cases
}
```

Then the caller could do:

```
Splitter<Company, Department> split = getSplitter(Company.class, Department.class);
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass key information(Company.class and Department.class) dynamically, by reading it from some external configuration file?